# Symfony2 Doctrine: change DateTime format

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to change format of date to Y-m-d H:i:s. This is what I tried to do

*CollectionController*

```
     date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
     $dateAdded = (new \DateTime())->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
     $collection->setDateAdded($dateAdded);
```

*Collection class*

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="date_added")
 */
private $date_added;

public function setDateAdded(DateTime $date_added)
    {
        $this->date_added = $date_added;
        return $this;
    }
```

But I have this error

Argument 1 passed to CollectionBundle\Entity\Collection::setDateAdded() must be an instance of DateTime, string given

Answer (score 2):

The signature of your method is:

```
public function setDateAdded(DateTime $date_added)
{
    $this->date_added = $date_added;
    return $this;
}
```

You're trying to pass string (format returns string):

```
$dateAdded = (new \DateTime())->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$collection->setDateAdded($dateAdded);
```

Pass the object reference:

```
$dateAdded = new \DateTime('NOW');
$collection->setDateAdded($dateAdded);
```

Comment: This didn't help me change format. I get 'y-m-d' format

Comment: Run php app/console doctrine:schema:update to check whether column type is 'datetime' not 'date'

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple. If you make a `format` get a string as return and you don't have and DateTime object.

So format your DateTime object in your Entity or remove Type hinting for DateTime in your entity.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Here you can see you get a formatted date `string`.

```
public function setDateAdded(DateTime $date_added) {
    $this->date_added = new \DateTime();
    return $this;
}
```

Something like this.

Sorry my mistake. If you declare a field as DateTime you can set the DateTime object directly. If you read it from your database you can format it.

Comment: Thanks, but now I have this error: Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: If have added my answer. You can set it directly to your database and format it if you read it.

Answer (score 0):

You should store date as a datetime object, not a string. Formatting them is the responsibilty of the view layer, Don't change anything, just pass the DateTime object to the `setDateAdded` method, eg.:

```
$collection->setDateAdded(new \DateTime());
```

and in twig file:

```
{{ object.dateAdded|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}
```